# Throwing Callback functions with different names

Tags: javascript, arrays, mutation-observers

I'm newbie in coding and this is my first question, so I'll try to explain very clear.

I have an image slider and I'm trying to change text in every slide. I have Mutation Observer in JavaScript which is watching classlist for class changing, so when a div have "active" class, I'm throwing a callback function.

A carousel have lot of image sliders inside;

```
carousel.forEach(e=>{
    let i= 1;
    let workOnClassAdd=`workOnClassAdd${i}`
    new ClassWatcher(e, 'active',workOnClassAdd,workOnClassRemoval)
    i++;
})

function workOnClassAdd1(){};
function workOnClassAdd2(){};
.
.
```

So in this code, I'm trying to create watchers with different functions but workOnClassAdd is looking like a string, so I got "this is not a func" error. How can i throw different variables in this forEach method?

Thanks anyway, good coding :)

Comment: Put the functions in an object or a map, then fetch them by name.

Comment: Hello VLAZ, this is what I'm looking for! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write functions that return functions. Something like:

```
function getCallbacksFor(iValue) {
  return [
    function workOnAdd() {
      console.log('add class work for', iValue);
    },
    function workOnRemove() {
      console.log('remove class work for', iValue);
    },
  ];
}

carousel.forEach((e, idx) => {
  new ClassWatcher(e, 'active', ...getCallbacksFor(idx))
})
```

Comment: This is also work! Thanks Chase, i like your way much!